# Applet doesnt connect on web service

Tags: java, web-services, maven, applet

I'm trying to build a simple example using Applet Form with web service in a localhost. The objective is create a connection with web service and get a captcha and show on screen. In previous Design when I try use on web browser where It fail when he call getNameofServiceport(), but it work when I execute it on Netbeans."Sure I known commands a different". i need yet discover a way to debug applet on browser where responses here not helped because the vars in Home directory don't exist.

What Im using:

- Web service with maven
- I generate stubs with wsimport and import to a normal Java application    where I have Applet form
- Last opensuse O.S
- Last GlassFish Server

i see many responses here in another issues here but did not help so much till now to solve this problem.

What I tried till now:

1. Applet Tag configuration
2. MANIFEST attributes
3. jarsigner "Across sites I see me feel afraid because is note secure"
4. Applet policy "I'm not sure if this could be used in web browser"
5. Read stackoverflow similar issues

Sources

-[Applet tag](http://www.docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jfc/ch07_02.htm)

-[Validate jar files](http://web.univ-pau.fr/~munier/temp/jdk-7u45-apidocs/technotes/guides/jweb/index.html)

**UPDATE 1**

Lets try with this example to help people understand what i want to do:

**Server Side**

```
    package test.example.serviceexample;

    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    import javax.jws.WebParam;

    /**
    *
    * @author felipe
    */
    @WebService(serviceName = "WebServiceHelloWord")
    public class WebServiceHelloWord {

    /**
    * This is a sample web service operation
    * @param txt
    * @return 
    */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
      public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
      return "Hello " + txt + " !";
     }
    }
```

**Generate Stub File**

```
    wsimport -d . -keep -verbose  -clientjar example.jar http://localhost:8080/ServiceExample/WebServiceHelloWord?WSDL
```

**Creating a Applet to Web Application**

1. Create a Java Program
2. Add Apllet form
3. Add example.jar on Libary Jar
4. Edit souce applet to conect on port

**Source Code Client**

```
    package applethelloword;

    import test.example.serviceexample.*;

    /**
    *
    * @author felipe
    */
     public class AppletHelloWord extends java.applet.Applet {

        private WebServiceHelloWord_Service port;
        private WebServiceHelloWord sMyReturn;
    /**
    * Initializes the applet AppletHelloWord
    */
     public void init() {
        try {
             java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   initComponents();
              }
            });
          } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
          }
        }

       /**
       * This method is called from within the init() method to initialize the
       * form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
       * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
       */
       // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
       private void initComponents() {

             jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
             jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
             jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
             jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

             jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Cantarell", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
             jLabel1.setText("Say WORD !!!");

             jButton1.setText("PRESS HERE");
             jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                     jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
               }
               });

              javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
              this.setLayout(layout);
              layout.setHorizontalGroup(
          layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 295, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(162, 162, 162)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 39, Short.MAX_VALUE)
               .addComponent(jLabel2,  javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
              .addGap(23, 23, 23)
              .addComponent(jButton1)
              .addContainerGap())
      );
      }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    {                                         
         // TODO add your handling code here:

         port =  new WebServiceHelloWord_Service();
         sMyReturn = port.getWebServiceHelloWordPort();

        jLabel2.setText(sMyReturn.hello(jTextField1.getText()));

    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

**Execute It on Web service**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
          <title>Start Page</title>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body>
       <h1>Hello World!</h1>
           <applet archive="AppletHelloWord.jar,lib/example.jar" code="applethelloword/AppletHelloWord.class" width="500" height="400" >
    <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
      </applet>
      </body>
      </html>
```

**OBS**

After I read more about i see whn i get in sMyReturn = port.getWebServiceHelloWordPort(); occur a error where it dont connect in service and dont execute Remote command.

Comment: 1) *"I'm trying to build a simple example using Applet Form with web service **in a localhost"*** Why? Or more specifically. why did you mention localhost - how is that relevant to the immediate problem?  If it is possible to get the exact same error on a (secret - whatever) page at the business site, it doesn't relate to `localhost` ..  2) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again. ..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Thank you to reply folks. I posted a simple example on update.